# Weblogic JDBC connection pool keeps in suspended state when DB is back to normal

Tags: connection, weblogic, jdbc, pool

We have a JDBC connection pool on a weblogic 12c. When the backend database goes to offline, the pool goes into suspended state, and when the db is back online after a short period of time (say 5 min), the pool goes into running state. That's normal and what I expected weblogic will behavior.

But a couple of days ago the DB is crashed for about 30 min, and when the db is back online, the pool always keeps in suspended state, never return to running state. We have to re-start the pool manually. Is there any settings we can tune this behavior? Our test frequency is 600 sec and connection creation retry frequency is 0.

Answer (score 0):

How long are you actually waiting? Your configuration means you *could* have to wait up to 10 minutes, since test frequency is set to 600 seconds (10 minutes).
Connection creation retry frequency relates to a scenario in which you restarted weblogic during the DB outage (or any other trouble connecting to the DB) and the data source didn't get created during startup. This parameter tells weblogic the frequency with which it'll retry the connection creation. With your configuration, the data source would indeed stay down forever, but it wouldn't be in suspended state, it wouldn't even show up in the monitoring tab because it didn't get initialized. And your managed server would start up in ADMIN mode.
I personally like to set this parameter to something > 0 in all of my data sources. In my default wlst script, I set it to 300 seconds (5 minutes).